# MVC Razor - how to read hidden field value in razor code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working with a C# MVC Razor app where the previous person has written a dialog class containing a hidden field.  The dialog class calls *RenderPartial()* which contains some razor code to create some output using the hidden field.

The issue is, the razor code needs to access the value set in the hidden field, but I cannot find an example on how to do it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="bob" value="123" class="bobsname" />
@{ 
    this.ViewData.Add("BobKey:, 123);  <-- hard coded
    Html.RenderPartial("SomeDialog");
}
```

And in SomeDialog I can access the value using ViewData.ContainsKey("BobKey") etc.

Ideally, I'd like to get the value from the nearest hidden field with the class='bobsname' but also by nearest hidden field with name is also ok.

The reason for this is that the dialog is called from rows in a table when the user clicks on a field, so there may be multiple definitions of the hidden field but with different values.

**Note:**  The value is not accessible via the model or viewbag.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery to accomplish this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Find the nearest hidden field with class 'bobsname'
        var nearestHiddenField = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.bobsname');

        // If it's found, get its value
        if (nearestHiddenField.length > 0) {
            var bobValue = nearestHiddenField.val();
            console.log('Value of the nearest hidden field with class "bobsname": ' + bobValue);
        }
    });
</script>
```

If you want to access the value of the nearest hidden field without Jquery, you can achieve this by making use of Razor variables.

```
@{
    var bobValue = Request.Form["bob"];
    this.ViewData.Add("BobKey", bobValue);
    Html.RenderPartial("SomeDialog");
}
```

and In your "SomeDialog" partial view

```
<!-- SomeDialog.cshtml -->
<p>The value of the hidden field "bob" is: @ViewData["BobKey"]</p>
```